# visual studio debug and direct run .exe, the run time is huge different

Tags: c#, debugging

Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        sw.Start();
        for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++)
        {
            Console.Write(k.ToString() + "\t");
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(() =>
                {
                });
                t.Start();
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + "ms");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

I compile it in Debug mode, and I run it in two ways:

1: F5 in visual studio, it shows:**57100ms**;

2: find the .exe file, click it to run, it shows:**642ms**

My question is why they are so different?

Comment: Debugging inserts breakpoints. Lots of them. And not only.

Comment: first thank you, and can you give more info? e.g:microsoft official doc. and how to avoid it, the breakpoints?

Comment: Try running it through ctrl+F5 - this will launch the application without debugging. Debugger monitors each thread and that slows it down significantly. See the output window.

Comment: Well, you can first run it without debugging (Ctrl-F5 instead of F5).

Comment: In windows, it is ctrl + F5 to run without debugging, I see the output window which shows like :
The thread 0x364c8 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x36558 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x35668 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x36e1c has exited with code 259 (0x103)

Comment: And there are a lot of such messages. Writing them to the output window takes much time.

Comment: @michauzo thank you.

Comment: Cannot answer this question since it has been closed, hence commenting.The slowness is because the debugger is attached to your program on running with F5 - it translates to 'Run with debugger attached'. Please note that when you run the .exe file directly(or using Ctrl+F5), **the code in the exe is still compiled in debug mode**, the only difference is that the debugger is not attached to the code.
Refer this [MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/11/01/start-debugging-vs-start-without-debugging/) for a better explanation.

Comment: yes, it is. thank you.